# Helper to distinguish between two instances of same application

Tags: windows, software-testing

We test our system on two different test environments. While opening two instances of desktop application (one for each test environment) - after login window there is no way to distinguish which application works on given environment.

I heard that there was an application for Windows XP which marked each opened application with additional border using different colors. This would be useful but I can't find it and I don't know if that would work on Windows 7.

Do you know any solution for our problem?

Comment: I don't know if this is what your looking for but I know sandboxie opens programs with a yellow border around the application window, could sandboxie work?

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out. But I'm afraid it will block some functionality of application.

Comment: It may, some programs don't run correctly in sandboxie, I'll look for something else

Comment: Why not use the process ID as a unique identifier for each instance?

Comment: @rrirower I think he wants a more visual identifier

Comment: Why not *display* the process ID?  He could put it in a dark corner where it would not affect most users.

Comment: Application creates many child windows. Main problem is to tell which window belongs to which parent.